# Paypal SDK vs MPL integration

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is my first time integrating PayPal payments into an Android App. Could someone explain to me what is the difference between both so I know which one to use? I have to mention that my app will have to send payments to 2 receivers (Parallel payment).